# xamarin - ImageView show black image after take picture from camera of from gallery

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I face issue with [CircleImageView](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CircleImageView-Xamarin.Android) after selecting image from gallery or take pic from Camera it show black image , it works just fine in lolipop but this issue raised in kitkat version

here is my code

my xml imageView

```
 <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
              android:id="@+id/storeImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/misr_pharmacy"
                 />
```

my C# code

```
 private void ChooseImage()
        {
            String[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };

            using (var dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
            {
                dialogBuilder.SetTitle("Add Photo");
                dialogBuilder.SetItems(items, (d, args) => {
                    //Take photo
                    if (args.Which == 0)
                    {
                        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
                        {
                            if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForWriteExternalStorage())
                            {
                                bool _ShouldShowRequest = ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PublicKeys.WriteExternalStoragePermission);

                                marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForWriteExternalStorage(_ShouldShowRequest);
                            }

                        }
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                    //Choose from gallery
                    else if (args.Which == 1)
                    {

                        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
                        {
                            if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForReadExternalStorage())
                            {

                               bool _ShouldShowRequest = ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PublicKeys.ReadExternalStoragePermission);
                                marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForReadExternalStorage(_ShouldShowRequest);
                            }

                        }
                        dispatchChoosePictureIntent();
                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.Show();
            }


        }
        private void dispatchTakePictureIntent()
        {
            var takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            File photoFile = null;
            try
            {
                photoFile = FileUtils.createImageFile();
                currentFilePath = "file:" + photoFile.AbsolutePath;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (photoFile != null && takePictureIntent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
            {
                takePictureIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(photoFile));
                this.StartActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }


        }
        private void dispatchChoosePictureIntent()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                {

                    // Handle the newly captured image
                    Android.Net.Uri imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(currentFilePath);
                    iv_profileImage.SetImageURI(imageUri);


                }
                else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                {
                    // Handle the image chosen from gallery

                    string selectedImagePath = FileUtils.GetPath(this, data.Data);

                    iv_profileImage.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File (selectedImagePath)));

                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case PublicKeys.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            //Permission granted
                            Snackbar.Make(layout, "camera permission is available", Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();
                            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Permission Denied :(
                            //Disabling functionality
                            Snackbar.Make(layout, GetString(Resource.String.camera_permission_denied), Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();

                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case PublicKeys.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            //Permission granted
                            var snack = Snackbar.Make(layout, "camera permission is available", Snackbar.LengthShort);
                            snack.Show();

                            dispatchChoosePictureIntent();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Permission Denied :(
                            //Disabling functionality
                            var snack = Snackbar.Make(layout, "Camera permission is denied.", Snackbar.LengthShort);
                            snack.Show();
                        }
                    }
                    break;



            }
        }
```

my helper class to create file

```
public static File createImageFile() 
        {
            //create an image file name
         string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
        string imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        File image = File.CreateTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents

        return image;

    }



 public static string GetPath (Context context , Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
             bool isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat;

            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(context, uri))
            {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
                {
                     string docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
                    string[] split = docId.Split(':');
                     string type = split[0];

                    if (string.Equals("primary" , type , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + split[1];
                    }

                    // TODO handle non-primary volumes
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri))
                {

                     string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
                    Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(
                            Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), long.Parse(id));

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri))
                {
                     string docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
                     string[] split = docId.Split(':' );
                     string type = split[0];

                    Android.Net.Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".Equals(type))
                    {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                    }
                    else if ("video".Equals(type))
                    {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                    }
                    else if ("audio".Equals(type))
                    {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                    }

                     string selection = "_id=?";
                     string[] selectionArgs = new string[] {
                    split[1]
            };

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if (string.Equals("content" , uri.Scheme , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if (string.Equals("file", uri.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return uri.Path;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
        public static string getDataColumn(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection,
                string[] selectionArgs)
        {

            ICursor cursor = null;
            string column = "_data";
             string[] projection = {
                column
            };

            try
            {
                cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.GetString(column_index);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }


        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
         */
        public static bool isExternalStorageDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
         */
        public static bool isDownloadsDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
         */
        public static bool isMediaDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
        }
```

Comment: Probably the image file does have a too big resolution to construct a bitmap for it in available memory. Try with smaller pictures first.

Comment: Do not mess around with `GetData()` to construct another uri. You have already an uri! Use `iv_profileImage.SetImageURI(data.Data);` directly.

Comment: I have tried small resolution image the same issue , and I have to make special handling with uri  as I support kitkat version

Comment: No. You dont have to do anything special for kitkat. Just use `data.Data` directly as i suggested. You can throw away a lot of code then.

Comment: yea you are right sir thanks , I fix black image issue as well

Answer (score 1):

Do not mess around with `GetData()` to construct another uri.

You have already an uri!

Use `iv_profileImage.SetImageURI(data.Data);` directly.

Answer (score 0):

just put your `CircleImageView` inside container in my case `FrameLayout`

and set `layerType` to `software`   to be like this `android:layerType="software"`

here is my xml code

```
<FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
          android:layerType="software"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35.3dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
          <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
              android:id="@+id/storeImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/misr_pharmacy"
                 />

        </FrameLayout>
```

hope this help any one face same issue